# Why does 'bundle install' fail and force me to 'gem install' myself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have executed the command

```
bundle install
```

In my Ruby on Rails projects, and I get the following error message

```
An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.10), and Bundler cannot continue. 
Make sure that `gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

After executing

```
gem install bcrypt -v '3.1.10'
```

the problem disappears. My question is why it's necessary sometimes to install some gems in a direct way?

Comment: What does your Gemfile look like?

Comment: check out this [link](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/364). It may be a file path issue.